# Did Neil lie to Mr Keating in Dead Poets Society?

Tags: analysis, dead-poets-society

In the part where Neil breaks the news to Mr Keating (in a classroom) that his father, although reluctant, would let him play in the show, Mr Keating is overjoyed and asks him if he had told his father exactly what he had told him the previous night (the previous night Neil goes to Mr Keating's room and tells him that his father won't let him perform in the play).

Neil stutters through this part (in the classroom) and gives vague answers without much eye-contact. Mr Keating does not look so convinced. Furthermore, his father's extreme anger seeing Neil perform makes me think that Neil had actually never talked to his father about how much he loved acting before he talked to Mr Keating that day. What is the explanation behind this?

Answer (score 5):

A boy lied to his father.  Not really such an uncommon thing.

The fact is, Neil's father is spending a lot of money on a private school so that one day his son will become some type of leader, or at least have a "respectable" (my quotes) job which will be financially beneficial.  He's not paying that kind of money for his son to become an actor.  However, since Neil loves the theater he lied to Mr. Keating so he could perform in the play.

Comment: Um, Mr Keating is his school teacher. What does that have to do with him lying to his father?

Comment: I don't think Mr Keating would have stopped Neil if he hadn't talked to his father at all.

Comment: A lie by omission is still a lie.  And if Neil had asked his father and his father said "No", the part would have gone to someone else.